# weblogic errors in wls EncryptionServiceException: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding

Tags: weblogic

sorry for the delay.
to update to the question:

weblogic version is 12c.   our installs are a bit different as we do not manually create a domain. we used a piece of software called maintenix that gets installed on top of the weblogic base install and it creates a domain the app runs under admin server

thank you

Hi everybody I am trying to decrypt the login and password for my WebLogic console

So I researched and seems this should work but i get the error below:

here are more details:

```
    [webmstr@Ready4Use Oracle_Home]$ cd oracle_common/common/bin/
    [webmstr@Ready4Use bin]$ ./wlst.sh
    
    Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
    
    Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
    
    Type help() for help on available commands
    
    wls:/offline> domain = "/webapps/maint/maint35_install/domain/"
    wls:/offline> service = weblogic.security.internal.SerializedSystemIni.getEncryptionService(domain)
    wls:/offline> encryption = weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService(service)
    wls:/offline> print encryption.decrypt("{AES}WDhZb5/IP95P4eM8jwYITiZs01kawSeliV59aFog1jE=")
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
        at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:144)
        at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:192)
        at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding.
```

I am suspecting some env item is not set properly but for the life of me I cannot see it (I did run setDomainEnv.sh before hand.

Comment: What is the weblogic server version ?
Are you sure to use the same domain as the one used to encrypt the password ?

Comment: weblogic version is 12c.

Comment: Are you sure to use the same domain as the one used to encrypt the password ?